# Digital Ocean - Moving codeigniter app from local to server throws (ip address) is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Trying to move codeigniter app from local to the cloud but getting an error saying This page isn’t working (ip address) is currently unable to handle this request.

> HTTP ERROR 500.

Renamed Login.php controller and made it login.php, Hence this error , otherwise it says

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

Tried Everything from other posts like changing config file `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';` to path info, query string, request uri, orig path info but doesn't seem to work. Made changes to the server also enabling mod_rewrite. Below i am attaching the routes.php, database.php, config.php, index.php and login.php i.e the controller.

routes.php

```html
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
| example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There area two reserved routes:
|
| $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
| $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['organizational_structure']='designation/organizational_structure';

$route['timesheet']='dtm/timesheet';
$route['timesheet/time_track']='dtm/time_track';
$route['timesheet/view_time_track']='dtm/view_time_track';
$route['timesheet/schedule']='dtm/schedule';
$route['timesheet/holidays']='dtm/holidays';
$route['404_override'] = 'error_404';
$route['404_override'] = '';





/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

database.php

```html
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'latestdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Config.php has the line $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

index.php

```html
<?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations dependihng on your
 * current environment. Setting the environmethe codent also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
 define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
 switch (ENVIRONMENT)
 {
  case 'development':
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
  break;
 
  case 'testing':
  case 'production':
   error_reporting(0);
  break;

  default:
   exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
 }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
 $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
 $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
 // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
 // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
 // $routing['directory'] = '';

 // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
 // $routing['controller'] = '';

 // The controller function you wish to be called.
 // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
 // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

 // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
 if (defined('STDIN'))
 {
  chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
 }

 if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
 {
  $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
 }

 // ensure there's a trailing slash
 $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

 // Is the system path correct?
 if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
 {
  exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
 }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
 // The name of THIS file
 define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

 // The PHP file extension
 // this global constant is deprecated.
 define('EXT', '.php');

 // Path to the system folder
 define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

 // Path to the front controller (this file)
 define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

 // Name of the "system folder"
 define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


 // The path to the "application" folder
 if (is_dir($application_folder))
 {
  define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
 }
 else
 {
  if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
  {
   exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
  }

  define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
 }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

login.php

```html
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data;

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('cookie');  
  $this->load->library('session');
  $is_admin_logged_in = $this->admin_init_elements->admin_logged_in_status();  
  global $USER;
  if($is_admin_logged_in == TRUE){
   redirect('home');
   //;
        }

        //populate viewfor header / footer elements
        
        $this->admin_init_elements->init_elements('N');
  $this->load->model('mod_login');
  
    }

    function index(){
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home
  
  $this->data['message']='';
  $this->data['msg_class'] = '';
  $post_array=$this->input->post();
  
  $data['old_images']=$this->mod_common->getBgImages();
  
  if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
  {
   //echo $this->input->cookie('username');
   $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->check_cookie_login());
   if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
     redirect('home');    
   }else{
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
   }
  } 
       if($this->input->post('action')=='adminLogin'){
  
  //print_r($this->input->post()); die;
    
   if(isset($post_array['remember'])){
    $username_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'uusername',
     'value'  => $post_array['username'],
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );
    
    $password_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'userpass',
     'value'  => $post_array['userpass'],
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );
    
    $remember_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'remember',
     'value'  => 'on',
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($username_cookie); 
    $this->input->set_cookie($password_cookie); 
    $this->input->set_cookie($remember_cookie); 
    //die;
    
   }
   else
   {
    if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
    {
     if($this->input->cookie('uusername') != $post_array['username'])
     {
      delete_cookie("remember");
      delete_cookie("uusername");
      delete_cookie("userpass");
     }
    } 
   }
   
   $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->validate_admin_login());
   if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
    $companyName = $this->input->post('company');
    //echo $companyName;
    //$this->session->set_userdata($companyName);
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
     'company'  => $companyName    
    ));
    //$this->load->database($companyName, TRUE);
    //print_r($this->session->userdata); 
    //die;
     redirect('home');    
   }else{
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
   }
  } /*else if(isset()){
   
  }*/
  
  
 ///////////////////////
  $this->data['cookieRemember'] = $this->input->cookie('remember');
  $this->data['cookieUsername'] = $this->input->cookie('username');
  $this->data['cookiePassword'] = $this->input->cookie('userpass');
  //echo $this->data['cookieRemember'];echo $this->data['cookieUsername']; echo $this->data['cookiePassword'];
 //////////////////////
 
  $this->data['cookiename']  = $this->input->cookie('name', false);
  $this->data['cookieimage'] = $this->input->cookie('image', false);
  
  $sess_msg = $this->session->userdata('session_msg');
  $session_msg_class = $this->session->userdata('session_msg_class');
  if(isset($sess_msg) && $sess_msg!= ''){
   $this->data['message']=$sess_msg;
   $this->data['msg_class'] = $session_msg_class!=''?$session_msg_class:'gagal';
  }
        //render full layout, specific to this function
        $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
 function forgot_password(){
   $this->load->view('send_reset_link', $this->data);
 }
 
 function send_pass_reset_link(){
  
  $post_array=$this->input->post();
  if($post_array['email']!='') { 
  $email_id=$post_array['email'];
  
  $user_id=$this->mod_common->get_userid($post_array['email']);

  foreach($user_id as $key){
   $id=$key['id'];
  }
  
  if($id>0){
  
  $link=base_url().'login/reset_password/'.$id;
  $message_body="<table>
      <tr><td style='padding:10px 0px'>Dear User,</td></tr>
      <tr><td style='padding:10px 0px'>You have received this communication in response to your request to reset your online portal account password. Please find below the link to reset your password</td></tr>
      <tr ><td style='padding:10px 0px'><a href='".$link."' style='background:#86c337;text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px;color:#fff'> Reset Password </a></td></tr>
      <tr ><td style='padding:10px 0px'>Regards,<br>Unfold</td></tr>
      
        </table>";

  /*-------------------------*/
  //sending pass reset mail 
   $this->load->library('email');
  $config['protocol']  = 'sendmail';
  $config['mailpath']  = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
  $config['charset']   = 'iso-8859-1';
  $config['wordwrap']  = TRUE;
  $config['mailtype']  = 'html'; 
  $this->email->initialize($config);
  
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from("info@unfold.com","Admin");//email id and name of the sender
  $this->email->to($email_id); // email id of the recipient
  $this->email->subject("Reset Password"); //The subject line
  $this->email->message($message_body);
  $this->email->send();
  //$this->email->clear();
  //show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
  //die;
  /*-------------------------*/
  $this->data['reset_link_msg']="An email with the password reset link has been sent to your mail address.";
  }else{
  $this->data['reset_link_msg']="Sorry! The email entered is not in our database.";
  } 
  } else {$this->data['reset_link_msg'] = '';}
  
  $this->load->view('send_reset_link', $this->data);
  
 } 
 
 function reset_password(){
  if($this->input->post()){ 
   
   $post_array=$this->input->post();
   $this->data['reset_msg']=$this->mod_common->reset_password($post_array);
   $this->load->view('reset_password', $this->data);
  }
  
  if($this->uri->segment(3)!=''){
   $this->data['id']=$this->uri->segment(3);
   $this->load->view('reset_password', $this->data);
  }
  else{
   redirect('login');
  }
 }

  
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
    // Admin authentication ----------
}
  
?>
```

.htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

apache error log contains some error as below

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   admin_logged_in_status() on null in
>   /var/www/html/singlecodebase/Feb152017/application/controllers/login.php:10\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/singlecodebase/Feb152017/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308):
>   login->__construct()\n#1
>   /var/www/html/singlecodebase/Feb152017/index.php(202):
>   require_once('/var/www/html/s...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/singlecodebase/Feb152017/application/controllers/login.php
>   on line 10

Commented the line in login controller but still does not work. Please help

I am using these versions on localhost - Current PHP version: 5.6.31, Codeigniter Version 2.1.3, Mysql version 10.1.25-MariaDB

On digital ocean Server version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: You should upgrade to CodeIgniter 3 and the report back, as some of these types of issues are often resolved when the framework is upgraded.

Comment: Just check your default controller name should start with CAPITAL.